# Everytime I do the CanPlaceOn command it says i'm wrong

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

My command is

```
/give @p lever 1 0 {"can_place_on" : {"blocks" : ["diamond"]}}
```

and it keeps responding by saying

> Component 'can_place_on' is not a supported component.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You probably mean `diamond_block`.

```
/give @p lever 1 0 {"can_place_on":{"blocks":["diamond_block"]}}
```